# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mytrigger\xa0_init__.py'

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

Does anyone know why I'm seeing this when I launch the debugger - to attach to a container.

Why doesn't it say `"__init__.py"`?
And why can't it resolve the path?

I'm able to debug the function with F5, but not the container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.8

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

launch.json:

```
{
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ]
        }
```

Docker-Compose.debug

```
services:
  qfunc:
    image: qfunc
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: ["sh", "-c", "pip install debugpy -t /tmp && python /tmp/debugpy --wait-for-client --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 mytrigger\__init__.py "]
    ports:  
      - 5678:5678
```

Comment: In your `Dockerfile` shouldn't  `mytrigger\__init__.py` be `mytrigger/__init__.py` instead? (/ instead of \\)?

Comment: I haven't changed any code from what was generated by func init --docker.

Comment: @Kashyap was correct. It should be '/'.  This error was introduced when selecting 'Add Docker files to workspace which prompts you to select your.py file from a dropdown. The option displayed corrupts the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Dockerfile`  `mytrigger\__init__.py` should be `mytrigger/__init__.py` instead (`/` instead of `\`).